WPF main thread not blocked by WaitOne method when Windows.Deactivate event arrives
I have a very strange problem with my WPF application.
When an AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() method is called on the main thread, when the window loses focus and the Windows.Deactivate method is called, the handler function is executed even if it is called in the main thread too.
A code example of the issue:
private AutoResetEvent m_autoResetEvent;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
}

private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000000);
        m_autoResetEvent.Set();
    });

    m_autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
}

When the button is clicked the main thread stops at WaitOne(), but when the window loses focus the Window_Deactivated() method is hit from the main thread too.
I think the reason might be something similar to what reported here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/threading-model?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#reentrancy-and-locking
but this refers to lock and generic "Win32 window messages"...
The other thing is that this happens only with Windows.Activate and Windows.Deactivate events, not with other window events.
Do you know if these events have a special priority over the others and/or if there are other similar events?

It might be helpful to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Well, it's a pretty complicate situation indeed... I preferred to keep it simple like in the provided example, in which I'd expect a different behavior of the code.
